# Logic for inserting form with/without optional inputs into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Using: Brackets Html editor, MySQL Workbench

Simplified, I have a database with these tables

1. (main table) person

   - idperson PK NN UN AI
   - *fk_job NN UN (foreign key refering to idjob)
   - fn NN
   - ln NN
2. job

   - idjob PK NN UN AI
   - jobname NN
3. adress

   - idadress PK NN UN AI
   - *fk_person NN UN (foreign key refering to idperson)
   - adress NN

and this form. In the form it is required to fill on one adress, and optional to fill in a second one.

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("localhost","user","password","database");
if ($con->

connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('. $con->connect_errno .') '. $con->connect_error .'');
    }

$job_sql = "SELECT idtype, typename FROM type;";
$job_data = $con->query($job_sql);

//insert if(isset()) here

$con->close();
?>
<form method="post">
 <select name="typeSlc" required>
  <option disabled selected>_</option>
  <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($job_data)) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['jobid'];?>"><?php echo $row['jobname'];?></option>
  <?php } ?>
 </select>
 <input name="fnTxt" required type="text">
 <input name="lnTxt" required type="text">
 <input name="adressTxt" required type="text">
 <input name="cityTxt" required type="text">
 <input name="opt_adressTxt" type="text">
 <input name="opt_cityTxt" type="text">
 <input name="submit" value="submit" type="submit">
</form
```

### Issue:

I want to send a transaction with one batch of queries to the server when 'opt_adress' isset and another when it is not, namely:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 if(isset($_POST['opt_adress'])) {
  $sql = sprintf  ("BEGIN;
                    INSERT INTO person (fk_job, fn, ln)
                        VALUES (%s, '%s', '%s');
                    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @id;
                    INSERT INTO adress (fk_person, adress)
                        VALUES (@id, '%s');
                    INSERT INTO adress (fk_person, adress, city)
                        VALUES (@id, '%s', '%s');
                    COMMIT;",
                    $con->real_escape_string($_POST['jobSlc']),
                    $con->real_escape_string($_POST['fnTxt']),
                    $con->real_escape_string($_POST['lnTxt']),
                    $con->real_escape_string($_POST['adressTxt']),
                    $con->real_escape_string($_POST['cityTxt']),
                    $con->real_escape_string($_POST['opt_adressTxt']),
                    $con->real_escape_string($_POST['opt_cityTxt']))
  ;
 } else {
  $sql = sprintf  ("BEGIN;
                    INSERT INTO person (fk_job, fn, ln)
                        VALUES (%s, '%s', '%s');
                    INSERT INTO adress (fk_person, adress, city)
                        VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '%s', '%s');
                    COMMIT;",
                    $con->real_escape_string($_POST['jobSlc']),
                    $con->real_escape_string($_POST['fnTxt']),
                    $con->real_escape_string($_POST['lnTxt']),
                    $con->real_escape_string($_POST['adressTxt']),
                    $con->real_escape_string($_POST['cityTxt']))
  ;
 }
 $con->query($sql);
 header("Location: samepage.php");
```

When I try to run the query it does not go through to the database (I am using MySQL Workbench). There are no error messages, yet the query is unsuccesful.

I want to insert batches if queries in a transaction if there are existing values in the optional inputs. Is this the correct string for that? Or is there a sleeker code I can use?

The form and database in this question is a simplified version on the one I use in reality.

Thanks in advance, -burrdie

Comment: You say there are no errors, but did you check for them? `$con->error;`

Comment: Run var_dump on your `$sql` and check for sql errors

Comment: And how do you know the query is successful? In this code, you never check for it. Also missing a comma `,` between the two last entries in the `sprintf` where you don't use `opt_adressTxt`. I also count more parameters than placeholders in both `sprintf`

Comment: The OP states they are using Workbench to check the query ...  With no errors it will say "Query Successful, 0 rows affected"

Comment: I don't believe for a second that the (first) query is successful, given the information we have. Because `adress.fk_person` is unique and AI, but there are two inserts for it *in the same query*, with the same SQL variable being used (the last inserted id). But there are errors in PHP too, so I'm quite sure there hasn't been done much error-checking. [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and [`$con->error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) -- check out these.

Comment: You are all correct in assuming I have not done a lot (or enough) error checking. I am still very much a novice in this field, and my knowledge in sql and php is limited. I have corrected some errors in the OP. @Qirel I will check those out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand the difference between a query and a batch of queries.

Since you have to execute **several separate queries**, you have to make several separate query() calls as well.

So change your code like this

```
$con->query("BEGIN");
$con->query(sprintf ("INSERT INTO person (fk_job, fn, ln)...");
$con->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @id");
// ...so on
```

and you'll be set.

Besides, it will let you write sleeker code, as you will be able to add your condition in the middle of the execution, thus not duplicating the code.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem, probably because I unwittingly removed an error while editing the wall of code to your sleeker solution. Just a small detail... Is the finishing ';' in sql code optional? I see you do not use it in your code.

Comment: It is not an unwitting removal, but the way this function works, as it can run only single query at once.